# Git over SSH using IP address on a different port

Tags: windows, git, ssh, ip-address, msysgit

I have a machine that i want to use as a Git server. There will be 2 contributors to the repository. I have set up an SSH account on the server which is a Windows machine. I pretty much followed http://www.timdavis.com.au/git/setting-up-a-msysgit-server-with-copssh-on-windows/ the blog and steps.

I can set up git --bare init on the server it does create some folders but it does not have .git folder - which I am thinking is how it is supposed to be.

I connect to ssh using 
ssh -p -port ssh://xx.xx.xxx

However, when I try to connect using

git push ssh://xx.xx.xxx:port/myrepository.git

myrepository.git is bare repository that I created on the server.

I get an error saying it does not seem to be a valid repository.

Please tell me what could be wrong?? I have a feeling that I am missing some configuration with the SSH.  I am new to both SSH and git.

thanks

Comment: Also, don't forget that you probably should have also entered `--shared` into the `git init --bare` command.

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.5.2.5/git-init.html

Comment: A git repo setup via `git --bare init` should _not_ have a .git folder. http://www.gitguys.com/topics/shared-repositories-should-be-bare-repositories/

Answer (score 5):

Where is `myrepository.git` located? Is it `C:\myrepository.git`?

If not, then from looking at Tim Davis's guide, you may want to specify the full path:

```
git push ssh://xx.xx.xxx:port/FULL/PATH/TO/myrepository.git
```

Comment: It is located at $home/my_account/myrepository.git.  I have tried the full path as ssh://xx.xx.xxx:port/home/my_account/myrepository.git  However, the home actually is c:/Program Files/ICW/ What do you think?

Comment: the remote machine you are using has no idea where the environment variable %HOME% is on your hosting machine (this changes by user...).  Best solution is to move the shared git repository to another location and use the full path as orip suggests above.

Comment: @SingleMalt - you need the full path from `C:\`. You can try using `%20` in the URL instead of the space in "Program Files", or move the repository like g19fanatic said.